# Javascript not working in rails asset pipeline

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I had written some jQuery for a partial which resided in a js.erb file. This jQuery turned into general functions and I decided to put into the asset pipeline instead i.e `assets/javascripts/myfile.js` and now the JavaScript is no longer working. I can see from the source code that the JavaScript is being loaded into the browser but it just isn't doing anything, but it was working before as a js.erb file.

What could be the problem?

In application.js I have

```
//= require jquery
//= require_tree .
```

Here is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#close").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().slideUp("slow");
  });


  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat : "yy-mm-dd"
    });
  });

  var player_count = $("#player option").length;


  $('#btn-add').click(function(){
    $('#users option:selected').each( function() {
      if(player_count >= 8){
        $('#select-reserve').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"       </option>");
    $(this).remove();    
      }else{
        $('#player').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
        $(this).remove();
        player_count++;
      }
    });
  });

  $('#btn-remove').click(function(){
    $('#player option:selected').each( function() {
      $('#users').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
      $(this).remove();
      player_count--;
    });
  });

  $('#btn-remove-reserve').click(function(){
    $('#select-reserve option:selected').each( function() {
      $('#users').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });

  $("#submit").click(function(){

    $("select option").prop("selected", "selected");

  });
});
```

I have noticed a new development, the js works after hitting reload. But whenever coming onto the page for first time (Direct from a link) it doesnt work.

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"? Does the js file need to be parsed by erb?

Comment: I dont know if the js file needs to be parsed by erb. All I know is that the functions are not doing anything.

Comment: First check that u included the js in controller
check this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017114/calling-javascript-functions-from-controller

Comment: @Navi I have tried with and without format js in the controller. No difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a turbolinks problem. 
The solution was to wrap my coffeescript in this:

```
ready = ->
// functions

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `application.js` is loading `myfile.js` before jQuery. Assuming this file still contains jQuery code, it will not run correctly since jQuery is not yet defined. Does your browser's JS console say something like: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"?

Note that Rails usually generates an `application.js` that looks like:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Also, if `myfile.js` contains ERB code, then you need to rename it to `myfile.js.erb` as @Flauwekeul suggests.

Comment: jquery is loaded first. my application.js file already looked like that. someone edited my question.

Comment: Is your jQuery code inside a `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` block?

Comment: Hi, just added that but it didn't make much difference

Comment: Hmmm... and your browser's JS console doesn't show any errors? Otherwise, I have no other ideas. You might want to include some/all of your JS code that isn't working.

Comment: i have just edited my question and added the js. The one thing that is actually working is the slideUp function.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem Jason Carty. Later on I found out that the issue was caused because I had:

  = javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr"

  = javascript_include_tag "application", 'data-turbolinks-track' => true

below "yield", in the bottom of my body tag. I moved it back to the top, after stylesheets and before "csrt_meta_tags", above my body tag and now works flawlessly.