# How can I call javascript functions from controller action using ROR

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Can anybody help me to resolve a small issue ?Actually I want to call some javascript functions from controller action method.I have written some code but it is not working.As I am totally new to ROR may be i have done mistake somewhere.Please check my below code snippets and modify these to run those successfully.

My code snippets are as follows.

views/users/index.html.erb:

```
<center>
    <h1>....Testing...</h1>
    <p>
        <a href="/users/browser"><button type="button">Check Browser</button></a>
    </p>
    <p>
        <a href="/users/time"><button type="button">Check Time</button></a>
    </p>
</center>
```

controller/users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index

    end
    def browser
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js{render :js => "my_browser();"}
        end
    end
    def time
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js{render :js => "my_time();"}
        end
    end
end
```

application.js:

```
function my_browser(){
    console.log('my browser function');
    var objOffsetVersion;
    if (objOffsetVersion=navigator.userAgent("chrome") != -1) {
        objOffsetVersion="chrome"
    };
    alert(objOffsetVersion) ;
}
function my_time(){
    var d = new Date();
    var currtime = d.getHours() * 100 + d.getMinutes();
    alert(currtime);
}
```

routes.rb

```
Jscript::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "users#index"
  get "users/browser" => "users#browser"
  get "users/time" => "users#time"
end
```

Please help me..Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017114/calling-javascript-functions-from-controller

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your links to use js format, as you are specifically telling your controller to handle js via format.js blocks:

```
<center>
  <h1>....Testing...</h1>
  <p>
      <a href="/users/browser.js"><button type="button">Check Browser</button></a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="/users/time.js"><button type="button">Check Time</button></a>
  </p>
</center>
```

As an alternative you could tell rails to always render js in the controller for all formats:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def browser
    render :js => "my_browser();"
  end

  def time
    render :js => "my_time();"
  end
end
```

Hope this provides some help.

Comment: As per your instruction after editing your code i am getting only string(i.e-my_browser) as result.But my objective is call the my_browser function and execute the alert prompt within it.Any more suggestion..?